# Blob column - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a column stored as blob data type in SQL Server 2014. I want to extract  the blob column into a string. I tried the following SQL statement, but long string is getting truncated by `varchar(max)` (due that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB))

```
SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(max), blobfield)
```

Is there a way in SQL Server to view complete string on blob to text conversion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *BLOB* = binary large object - that should be datatype  `VARBINARY(MAX)` - not `VARCHAR(MAX)` (that's a **textual** datatype - not a binary large object)

Comment: @marc_s  that wasn't always what it meant ( per comments here http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2008/03/13/lobs-are-either-blobs-or-clobs.aspx)

Comment: The 2 GB limit applies to all LOB types not stored in filestream. Sure the value is being truncated as opposed to the display?

Comment: Thank you all for the response.  Data type of this field is set to varbinary(max).  Problem is that when converting from blob to readable text - long string is getting truncated by varchar(max).  I want to get the whole string in a sql select.  Thanks.